# VB.NET disable the keyboard and mouse

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-7

I am looking to create a VB.NET application. when the application is opened it will disable the keyboard and mouse so if you hit any keys it does nothing and you can not move the mouse. (even if currently selected window is not that of application).

MUST WORK ON WINDOWS 7!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This would violate a key Windows principle: the user is in control. If you really need to do that you're probably going to have to write some low level windows/hardware hooks and I don't think vb.net is an appropriate language for such a task.  You can of course do this for your own application only - just ignore all keyboard and mouse events.

Comment: Thanks Daniel!
So as far VB.Net is considered, hocking is not supported. can i do it in C# ?

Comment: hocking? do you mean hacking or hooking or something else?  Bascially the answer is: you can't do it (see Rowland Shaw's answer)! Perhaps if you could explain *why* you want to do this, we might be able to offer some alternative solutions?

Comment: Sorry for typo mistake it was hooking. Basically i want to develop this application to be used by me for some security reasons. just an idea, and now doing POC on it, that it could be done or not.

Comment: Just out of interest. If you did somehow manage to do this, how would you regain control? By switching the machine off?

Comment: Yah that's another issue to consider. Thanks everybody for your answers/help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the mouse and the keyboard will be quite dead when you P/Invoke [BlockInput()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646290%28VS.85%29.aspx).  The three finger salute will be required.  Visit pinvoke.net for the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Not going to happen, and not something you should really be trying to achieve in isolation.

You can (rightly) never intercept <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, for example

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [global hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976490/limiting-the-mouse-to-a-form-without-the-ability-to-override/1977336#1977336). They are bad. They are evil. But the exist because every once in a while someone actually needs them.