# How can I disable a user's mouse and keyboard (Make the mouse not visible) in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, input

In visual basic how can I make the user's cursor not visible and the keyboard input not "enabled"?

Comment: Check here,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828925/vb-net-disable-the-keyboard-and-mouse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code. Add these API declarations to your declations section:

```
Private Declare Function BlockInput Lib "user32" Alias "BlockInput" (ByVal fBlock As Integer) As Integer
Private Declare Function ShowCursor Lib "user32" (ByVal lShow As Long) As Long
```

In your method, add the following code:

```
BlockInput 1
ShowCursor 0
```

To re-enable the keyboard and mouse, try the following:

```
BlockInput 0
ShowCursor 1
```

Comment: If your are using Grid control like ultra grid. You can use following code to in the keydown event of Ultrgrid     e.SuppressKeyPress = True